# Can I extract Datadog metrics info via Datadog REST API?

Tags: python, tags, metrics, datadog

Is there any way to extract the Tags info from DataDog via API for a specific metric?

I need the same info that the [Metrics Explorer](https://docs.datadoghq.com/graphing/metrics/explorer/) displays (list of hosts and tags), for only one metric.

I can retrieve the Tags filtered with a regular expression pattern:

```py
def _load_metrics(from_time, filter_pattern: str):
    regex = re.compile(filter_pattern)
    all_metrics = api.Metric.list(from_time)['metrics']
    filtered = list(filter(regex.search, all_metrics))
    if not len(filtered):
        print('No metrics found with filter {}'.format(args.filter_pattern))
        return None
    print("Found {} metrics matching filter '{}'".format(len(filtered), args.filter_pattern))
    return filtered
```

And I can get all the Hosts from a Metric with:

```py
def get_hosts_from_tag(tag_name: str):
    hosts = api.Hosts.search(q='hosts:', filter='tag={}'.format(tag_name))
    for host in hosts['host_list']:
        print(host['name'])
```

Using either the [datadogpy](https://datadogpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or the [DataDog API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/?lang=python#tags), **how can I get all the Tags from a Metric?**

Thanks